# How can remove a flat head screw that's in a hard to reach space?

Tags: light-fixture, screws, removal

I have an overhead light fixture and I need to remove the "cover" so I can change a bulb but the cover is held in place with metal brackets that have to be removed first  and they are attached to the main part on the ceiling with flat head screws.

The space between the cover and the ceiling is too small for pliers, and even small wrenches can't get enough grip. (*I'm wondering how it was even installed in the first place, tbh.*)

How can I remove it? Is there some kind of drill bit that could do the trick?

[image]

Comment: Guessing you are talking about knobs with a flat head instead of a  flat head screw with a slot or type of indentation.  Have you tried needle nose pliers?  They usually not that tight, fingers might turn them.

Comment: Use a ratchet??

Comment: It may be that you've missed a step: maybe the cover should be rotated to remove it without disturbing the brackets, for example. A photo will definitely help. Click the 'Edit' button below your post, then attach one or more photos using the mountain-and-sun icon in the editor.

Comment: I tried rotating, but only the cover is loose inside the brackets. The rest is stuck in place.

Comment: It's definitely a screw. I don't think I have needle nosed pliers or if they'd fit in the space?

Comment: Use a [Nut Driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nut_driver).

Comment: Are there nut drivers that can remove screws? I tried the ones I have  that were closest in size, but were either too big or too small.

Comment: Think I would try pulling on the U-shape holding cover, might be a spring holding it.

Comment: Just tried, and it's stuck in there really good.

Comment: @Alisa the picture is awful ... it looks like somebody spread grease on the camera lens ... please post a clear, in focus picture ... it is puzzling that you would post such a useless picture when you are wanting help with the light fixture

Comment: It's puzzling to me that you would be unnecessarily critical... I think the picture shows the situation well enough. There's a screw, it's in a tight place, and it's holding a bracket fixture in place.

Comment: I just tried pulling out a different bracket and it does have a spring. I think the other ones may just require more strength to pull out. So thanks, crip659! I would not have thought of that on my own. Problem solved : )

Comment: @Alisa  this is probably one those projects that work better with three hands.  Might just have one spring to hold, and other one/two fixed in place.

Comment: @Alisa I am sorry, but I cannot see the screw clearly enough to even identify the type  ... if I was needing help, I would keep taking pictures until I got one that showed the screw clearly

Comment: The screw in the picture does not look like it's meant to be removed for light bulb changing.  It may even be held on with a nut in the back, and if you remove it you'll have to take down the whole fixture to replace it.  Follow the advice in the answer that suggests finding a tool-less way to do this.  There must be some gimmick where one of these clips can be released.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn  what to do next with your post.

Answer (score 7):

On this style of light fixture, you'll usually find that one of the three clips is spring loaded and can be pulled horizontally away from the center. This allows you d to remove the glass.  There is no need to unscrew the clips.

Comment: Or you slide the cover into one of the clips so that the other side can come out. It might be spring loaded but typically they are tool-less removals and installs.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the metal-colored screw that sticks out parallel to the ceiling, use a nut driver: [image: nut driver]
(image from Klein Tools via Google)

on this hexhead (not "flat head") fastener. They're available in many sizes, and you'll need one to fit this fastener head.

Props to @brhans in comments.

Comment: OP had indicated that nut drivers were tried but they were too big or too small. Nut drivers come in fractional and metric sizes and the OP probably doesn't have a set of both which is why it didn't fit.

Comment: Obtaining and using a tool of the correct size would be good.